Is MTP only used for transferring media files?
Is MTP only used for transferring media files (image, video, and/or audio files), not files of any type, such as pdf files? Some said that MTP can be used for transferring files of any type, but it only shows me picture files (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/779420/)

If you see only pictures, you must have enabled PTP, not MTP. But note that MTP is an FTP-like server-client protocol, which has always been (kept) buggy. To have a true filesystem level access, you need to enable UMS.

From the linked question, you mentioned "Mode "transfer photos" allows me to do that $ aft-mtp-mount ~/media/phone/ but it only shows me images files not files of other types." that's PTP, as Irfan Latif has mentioned.

MTP can be used to transfer any type of file, including PDF files.  It is not restricted to only media files (images, videos, audio files).
